# Why is my team so bad?

Tags: counter-strike-source

I'm new to Counter Strike: Source and am playing with bots so I can sharpen my skills before playing with human players. However, I've noticed that my team of bots is virtually useless while the enemy team has incredible precision and accuracy. For example, my team will often run into a guarded bombsite and stare at the enemy while they get shot to pieces. Also, they will just sit there while the enemy team storm in and kill them all. I even had an instance where one of my team looked at an enemy on the balcony in de_inferno for a good 5 seconds before the enemy noticed and killed them. Because of this, I almost always lose and don't possess the skill to kill the entire enemy team on my own. Two questions:

1. Is this normal bot behaviour?
2. Are there any mods/options that fix this?

The bots are set to normal difficulty, and this happens whether I'm a terrorist or counter-terrorist.

Comment: How many bots are there

Comment: @stizzle84 11, it's a 6v6 game

Comment: It is possible the enemy bot team is set to a harder difficulty as you are an actual human. Bots are less and less advanced the easier they are, the hardest being borderline "hackers". I recommend that you instead go and play deathmatch against real human players. Instant respawn, all guns available to you (still respecting team tho). You also have special maps from the workshop you can get to practice spray and such against bots or stationary targets. Might be better for you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is normal behavior, your team bots are not as efficient as the enemy. It even comes from old CS:CZ, at least I remember it that way. The thing is the AI of your team behaves different because you are in such team. In other words, you are the captain of your team.

That means you have control of the behavior of your teammates. You need to send radio commands with the tactical decisions you think are best. Are they storming like crazy? Send a "Regroup team". Are they camping? Send a "Storm the front". If you spot an enemy and you send the command they will re-position to try to get a shot at him. Asking for status also lets you analyze the current situation.

So the thing is, when there are players on their teams bots do act different to allow players to direct them, because, as Raestloz said, is not quite fun to let the game play itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there any way I can change this (with mods etc)?

Comment: Hmmm, not that I know of. I doubt something like that exist as it would mess with the core game, something Valve does not like.Hmm, I used to play a lot like that, bots only, how about lowering the difficulty? Because you are right, most of the time, in those matches, is either you are the MVP/2MVP, or the team is wiped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad I'm not the only person that notices this. Yes, this does seem to be the normal bot behavior. I don't know how, but countless sessions of bot-filled teams pretty much confirms this in my case.

I personally thought that they're purposefully not as competent as the other, full-of-bot team to ensure your bot mates don't massacre the enemy team leaving you in the dust and have the game play itself, which I do think is stupid